# How to get resolution of Image in Android / Java

Tags: android

How can I find the resolution of any image in Android?

Comment: Do you mean the resolution (pixels per inch) or the dimensions (width and height)?

Comment: Hi Guffa, yes it's about "pixels per inch".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your image is on your res/drawable, you can use something like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.back);
bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 18):

The efficient way to get size of an image stored in disk (for example to get the size of an image file selected by the user for uploading) is to use `BitmapFactory.Options` and set `inJustDecodeBounds` to true. By doing so you will **get the size(Width and Height) of an image file without loading the entire image into memory**. This will help when want to check the resolution of an image before uploading.

```
String pickedImagePath = "path/of/the/selected/file";
BitmapFactory.Options bitMapOption=new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitMapOption.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pickedImagePath, bitMapOption);
int imageWidth=bitMapOption.outWidth;            
int imageHeight=bitMapOption.outHeight;
```

Comment: Returns 0 for width and height

Answer (score 5):

I think u are looking for this...

```
bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);

int imageWidth=bitmap.getWidth();

int imageHeight=bitmap.getHeight();
```

Try using this and let me know

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely learn how to phrase a question! Since you didn't provide any information i can only guess what you are doing. Maybe you can try this ...

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
iv.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the methodes :

```
myImageBitmap.getWidth(); 
myImageBitmap.getHeight();
```