# How should I determine the resolution of an image?

Tags: android, android-studio, game-development

What should be the resolution of an image for an image view,whose dimension is,for example-*100dp x 80dp?* I am developing a game where I need to load 15-16 images in a single activity,one for the background image and others are smaller size image views.Is it a good idea to use image resolution *1280x720* or *1920x1080* for each of these images?

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099059/how-to-get-resolution-of-image-in-android-java

Comment: Thanks for your response.But that's not my question.I don't need to find the dimension of an image,I need to know what should be the dimension of the image.

Comment: you can check this link 
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and also this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html  to avoid the stretching of the image